# What happens when multiple request of read or write occurs at the same time (same second) in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

1 RCU is 1 request per second, which is 4KB/sec per request for strong consistency and (4x2)8KB/sec per request for eventual consistency.

If an application gets 10 strong consistency read request per second and  the RCU is 1, what happens in this scenario? DynamoDB can only respond to only 1 request per second? What happens when the RCU is 10? DynamoDB can respond to 10 request per second?

What will happen to my application if I have tens and thousands of request to a table per second?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022398/what-should-be-done-when-the-provisioned-throughput-is-exceeded/48025081#48025081

Answer (score 1):

Your requests will be throttled.
See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html

```
If your read or write requests exceed the throughput settings for a table,
DynamoDB can throttle that request. DynamoDB can also throttle read requests 
exceeds for an index. 
Throttling prevents your application from consuming too many capacity units.
When a request is throttled, it fails with an HTTP 400 code (Bad Request) and 
a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException. 
The AWS SDKs have built-in support for retrying throttled requests (see Error 
Retries and Exponential Backoff), so you do not need to write this logic 
yourself.
```