# How should AWS DynamoDbExceptions be handled?

Tags: error-handling, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

How to handle software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbExceptions ? Does the DynamoDbClient client it self retry on these exceptions or should the implementation take care of that? Which exceptions does the the built in retry take care of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some errors the call can be retried, some should not be retried without fixing the call. AWS enumerate those [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html). Underneath each error you will see `OK to retry?`. An example of a call that can be retried without alteration is `LimitExceededException`, which indicates too many calls have been made from the client in a short space of time. The same call in future may succeed.

The only exception that the SDKs handle for you is the `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`. [By default the SDK will retry 10 times for you - this behaviour is configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022398/what-should-be-done-when-the-provisioned-throughput-is-exceeded/48025081#48025081). If the SDK still fails, it throws the error up to your application, so you still need to handle the error in some way.